# Run custom javascript on button click on Wix website using Velo

Tags: javascript, velo

I've installed the HelpScout Beacon chatbox on my Wix website which is loading just fine.

However I'd also like to manually trigger the chatbox when a user clicks on my "Contact Us" button. This is a simple well documented piece of API ([see docs](https://developer.helpscout.com/beacon-2/web/javascript-api/#beaconopenclose)).

It's literally 1 line of code:

```
Beacon('open')
```

I'm trying to run this code using Velo (see screenshot) but seems that the editor is not letting me access Beacon.

[image]

I find it hard to believe that I can't trigger this 1 line of code from my Wix website. I’ve also confirmed that it worked by simply running this from the JavaScript console in the dev tools of my browser.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light or offer a workaround on how to execute this one line of code.

Comment: The Velo code  runs in an isolated scope so it has no access to the global scope (`window`), that's why you can't call global functions. If your site has domain, you can add script to the site's head there you'll have access to the global scope.

Comment: Can I define a function in the site's head that can be called from Velo's isolated scope? Basically the main issue here is that I need to call some code in response to a button being clicked which is tied to a function in Velo.

Comment: I think not. But  if you have a premium plan so you can use [custom elements](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-adding-a-custom-element-to-your-site#what-are-custom-elements) so you can create your own button and call a global scope function

Comment: Ok the custom elements suggestion might do the trick however sounds like too much effort for what I’m trying to do. I ended up just creating a “Contact Us” page that says to click the bubble below. Thanks!

Comment: Product solution over technical solution, like :)